# Read text file line by line and store in a class?

Tags: java

I need some help with reading line by line from a file then put it into a class.
My idea is like this: I've saved everything in a text file, it's about 500 lines but this can change that's why I wan't the line number reader and then lnr/5 to get how many times I'll need to run the for loop. I wan't it to first take line 1,2,3,4,5 into a object, then 6,7,8,9,10 and so on. So basically I need each 5 lines go in seperatley.

Code:

```
public static void g_txt() {
    LineNumberReader lnr;
    String[] text_array = new String[500];
    int nu = 0;
    try {
        lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
        lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        //System.out.println(lnr.getLineNumber());
        lnr.close();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           text_array[nu] = line;
           nu++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }


}
```

as you can see, I now has it in an array. Now I need it to make so 1,2,3,4,5 and so on go in to this:

```
filmer[antalfilmer] = new FilmSvDe(line1);
filmer[antalfilmer].s_filmbolag(line2);
filmer[antalfilmer].s_producent(line3);
filmer[antalfilmer].s_tid(line4);
filmer[antalfilmer].s_betyg(line5);     
filmer[antalfilmer].s_titel(line1);
```

then antalfilmer++.

Comment: what's your question/problem?

Comment: I have no idea how to do so it splits, like I get 1,2,3,4,5 then start from 6 and go to 10, then 10 to 15 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void g_txt() {
    String[] text_array = new String[5];
    int nu = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text_array[nu] = line;
            nu++;
            if (nu == 5) {
                nu = 0;
                makeObject(text_array);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}

private static void makeObject(String[] text_array) {
    // do your object creation here
    System.out.println("_________________________________________________");
    for (String string : text_array) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    System.out.println("_________________________________________________");
}
```

Try this.

Comment: what is the purpose of the LineNumberReader here?

Comment: Its actually of no use, took code from Question.

I will edit.